# Next.js - Disable jump to anchor when using router.push()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Using next `10.2`, every time we push an URL with hash to the router, next is jumping to the anchor element.

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

router.push('/contact#about-us');
```

This also happens if I disable `scroll`

```
router.push('/contact#about-us', undefined, { scroll: false });
```

I would like to smooth scroll to the anchor element, rather than delegate this to next.js.

```
import React from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const LinkSmoothScroll = ({href, className, children}) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const linkClicked = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    router
      .push(href, undefined, {scroll: false})
      .then(() => {
        const el = document.getElementById(href);

        if ( typeof el !== "undefined" ) {
          // Since header element is fixed, and document height is not being
          // affected by fixed/absolute elements, we need to consider this
          // on the margin to be applied.
          const headerHeight = document.getElementById("nav-header")?.scrollHeight || 0;
          const scrollTopY = el.top + window.scrollY - headerHeight;

          window.scrollTo({
            left: el.left,
            top: scrollTopY,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }

      });
  }

  return (
    <a href={href} className={className} onClick={linkClicked}>{children}</a>
  )
}

LinkSmoothScroll.propTypes = {
  href: PropTypes.any,
  children: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string
}

export default LinkSmoothScroll;
```

I didn't found any way to disable this behavior, nor a tweak to avoid it.

Comment: That is because of #about-us, you are directing a user to an element with id `about-us`

Comment: @DedaDev the desired behavior is to jump to `contact` page, but `preventDefault` on jumping to element, dealing with that _manually_ (using smooth scroll).

Comment: How are you handling the scroll manually? Can you not prevent the default behaviour there?

Comment: @juliomalves what do you mean by `not prevent the default behavior`? I am doing `router.push()` after `preventDefault()` on click event in an element. As soon I remove the `router.push()` I am not having the jumping effect

Comment: The jump to anchor behaviour is not specific to Next.js, it happens because you're adding an anchor to the path on navigation (in this case when you call `router.push()`). You mention you want to deal with the jump manually - where are you doing that?

Comment: @juliomalves I updated the question by adding more notes

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts.

### #1 - Use CSS

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

### #2 - Don't use the target ID in the hash

Avoid the browser behavior by prefixing the ID in the hash so the matching element can't be found in the page (`#about-us` becomes `#prefix-about-us`). Then parse it on navigation and scroll to it with JS.

Neither approach is great in my opinion, default behaviors are best left intact if possible.